# Creating a atmosphere bubble in space with electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, space, atmospheric-science

would it be possible to contain an atmospheric bubble in space with a magnetic field, and wouldn't doing so protect it from solar radiation also?

Comment: Hint: what's the magnetic susceptibility of atmospheric gases?

Answer (score 1):

In short the answer is no !

To give a brief reasoning, lets take the two most abundant gases in our own atmosphere nitrogen and oxygen.

The magnetic behaviour of nitrogen is diamagnetic while that of oxygen is paramagnetic, so any magnetic cconfiguration that sustains one gas would push the other one away.

But even if all gases were paramagnetic, let's take a very simplistic model to see if it would have been possible.

Magnetic moment of all molecules are measured in bohr magnetons, lets be extremely generous and give the molecules that are going to be in our atmosphere a magneton number of $100000$ even then we get the magnetic moment of molecules in SI of the order $10^{-20} JT^{-1} $.

The magnetic field of the earth is calculated in gauss, so let's take an average field of 1G, that would be $10^{-4} T $

The net force on any one particle (we are assuming again that magnetic field is not shielded by other particles) will be approximately $$ F \approx \frac {\mu B}{R_e} $$ $$ F \approx 10^{-30} N $$

Even the gravitational force of earth on a measely hydrogen atom is of the order of $10^{-26} N $. So there is no chance that magnetic fields could sustain an atmosphere.

As far as protection from solar radiation goes, the magnetic fields only protect us against solar winds which have charged particles and not the harmful radiations such as UV. Ozone protects against the radiation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, diatomic oxygen is paramagnetic - it means that in magnetic field oxygen will be attracted to a magnet. I don't know numbers, but theoreticly it would be possible to create magnetic field so strong to make your oxygen 'bubble' in vacuum (it would be nice exercise!). Of course for practical needs we could 'dilute' our oxygen with nitrogen.

Second question, if we could make an ozone layer this way? The answer is no - for first, ozone is not paramagnetic, for second reason, if we want to live we need ozone far away from us - because of possibility of free radicals made by $O_3$ molecues.

But these are still theoretical considerations - if someone could calculate how strong should be magnetic force of our space station, it would be great. It would be great too if space station would not attract all metal space junk from around :)

Comment: A potential problem is that people are diamagnetic, so the same field that attracts the oxygen will repel the people trying to breath it.

Comment: @JohnRennie I'd rather live an electric than diamagnetic :-)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are referring to creating Magnetic and Gravitation (Electric and Magnetic) field bubbles, then the answer is yes! You can protect your space craft from coming into contact with Solar or Interstellar radiation.

In fact, the is preferred mean of propulsion in the Universe. Think like this two magnets with dissimilar poles attracts. Now those two dissimilar poles, one is point of origin say our SUN (solar system) and the second pole is say Alpha Centauris system.

In this case, the Magnetic and Gravitation fields are used not just to create a protective shell with 1g, but they are also used to propel the space craft in either direction at speeds beyond the speed of light. Solar System to Alpha Centauris system, few hours. :=)